# ¿ Volver a borrar subviews de un TableView tras un reload?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo una TableView al que en cada celda le agrego varios imageView.
En un momento de la aplicación tengo que cambiar los imgeView de una celda en una posición por otro imageView por lo tanto hago un reload del tableView.
El problema es que al hacer el reload me agrega encima del imageView anterior de la celda el nuevo. Lo que quiero es que antes de hacer el reload esta celda se borre todo los subviews, pero no encuentro el método para hacerlo.

Al añadir el imageView lo hago como 'imageView.tag = indexPath.row;' y 'cell addSubview:imageView'

Para borrar lo anterior, al inicio del código de carga del tableView lo hago como: '[[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row] removeFromSuperview];' para que cuando haga el reload también me borrepero no me funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo te diría que utilizaras 2 tipos de celdas diferentes para cada propósito. Así no tendrías que andar modificando por completo el UI de la celda en cuestión en tiempo de ejecución, y podrías aprovechar las celdas para poder ser reutilizadas, ahorrando recursos y siendo más eficiente.

No obstante, si aún así deseas poder eliminar todos los elementos de una celda, podrías hacer lo siguiente, en la clase que hereda de `UITableViewCell` que utilizas para la celda en cuestión, sobrescribe el método `prepareForReuse`, que es llamado cada vez que una celda va a ser reutilizada.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    contentView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
}
```

Si sólo quieres eliminar aquellos que sean `imageView`puedes modificar la línea por la siguiente:

```
contentView.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIImageView }).forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

EDIT:
Viendo que necesitas hacerlo en Objective-C sería así:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias me ha sido de mucha utilidad